# Dynamically retrieving page layout fields

Tags: lightning-aura-components, describesobject, describes

Is it possible to dynamically retrieve the fields on a certain layout? Possibly through something like DescribeLayout()? I'm having trouble finding examples on how to build a lightning component with just the fields that are in a specific page layout.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can synchronously pull details of a page layout in Apex using the [Apex Metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_metadata_retrieve_deploy.htm). Here's a quick example of walking through the layout metadata, freely adapted from [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/apex_metadata_api/units/apex_metadata_api_updates):

```
List<Metadata.Metadata> layouts = 
    Metadata.Operations.retrieve(Metadata.MetadataType.Layout, 
                                 new List<String> {'Account-Account Layout'});

Metadata.Layout layoutMd = (Metadata.Layout)layouts.get(0);
for (Metadata.LayoutSection section : layoutMd.layoutSections) {
    for (Metadata.LayoutColumn column : section.layoutColumns) {
        if (column.layoutItems != null) {
            for (Metadata.LayoutItem item : column.layoutItems) {
                System.debug(item.field);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you inspect the log after running this in Execute Anonymous, you'll find, e.g.,

> 11:56:57:079 USER_DEBUG [10]|DEBUG|Name
>   11:56:57:079 USER_DEBUG [10]|DEBUG|ParentId
>   11:56:57:079 USER_DEBUG [10]|DEBUG|Phone

and so forth.

Comment: One more question :)   Is it possible to getLabel() on the field?

Comment: Oddly, the [Metadata.LayoutItem](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Metadata_LayoutItem.htm#apex_class_Metadata_LayoutItem) class doesn't include the label, but you can easily get it from the Describe API.

Comment: Is there any way to get fields in the order present on the page layout?

Comment: @KrishnanMishra Metadata mentioned above has layout sections with layout columns with fields in the order like in page layout in UI. You can also use Tooling API for this